# CSS: Aligned tables overlapping DIV container

Tags: html, css

I created two tables, which are displayed side by side using the attribute `align="left"` & `align="right"` in the html source code. I packed these tables into a div container with the assigned class `outerdiv`, so that I can add a linear-gradient background behind them. Unfortunately, the tables do not get displayed inside of the div.

I tried adding `table-layout:fixed;` to `.table`, as some sites recommended me. I also set `border-collapse:separate;` to the table cell.

How can I place the background correctly behind the tables?

```css
.table {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 1% !important;
  background: red;
  border-spacing: 20px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.outerdiv {
  border: 1px solid rgb(164, 164, 164);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(222, 222, 222)) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <table class="table" align="left">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apples
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table" align="right">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bananas
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block` to your `outerdiv` class. This will correctly wrap the tables inside of the parent `div`. Like so:

```css
.table {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 1% !important;
  background: red;
  border-spacing: 20px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.outerdiv {
  border: 1px solid rgb(164, 164, 164);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(222, 222, 222)) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <table class="table" align="left">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apples
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table" align="right">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bananas
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Also, Maximillian makes a good point in his post about the `align` attribute you seem to be using. It is no longer used in HTML5. Instead, either give your tables `float: left`. Like this:

```css
.table {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 1% !important;
  background: red;
  border-spacing: 20px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  float: left;
}
.outerdiv {
  border: 1px solid rgb(164, 164, 164);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(222, 222, 222)) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apples
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bananas
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the `align` attribute is deprecated in HTML, so instead of `align` I would use CSS `float` instead. Secondly if you use floats and want your div to expand to surround its contents, you will also need an element that clears them - in this case I've used a `div` with `clear: both` since it's the most straightforward, but there are more elegant clearing solutions too (some using pseudoelements).

Here is a live demo of your tables being properly wrapped in their div:

```css
.table {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 1% !important;
  background: red;
  border-spacing: 20px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.outerdiv {
  border: 1px solid rgb(164, 164, 164);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(222, 222, 222)) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <table class="table" style="float: left;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apples
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table" style="float: right;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bananas
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```